# Access 2013 query only pulls the first record

Tags: sql, ms-access

i'm hopeing someone will be able to solve this. I have a combo box which shows the records that are available to view. Upon selecting a record, my query updates without any problem. I tried to use this query within a subform however, for some reason, only the first record in the data set is shown upon selection. When I select anyting else from the available options, the subform doesn't change. However, when i re-select the first record, it shows. 
The weird thing is, that when I change the drop down box to say the 2nd record & run the query itself, the desired record shows within the query designer.

To explain further: the combo box is called searchByAcc_cb. This is set so that it retrieves the account name & various other fields from the same table. Below that, there is a subform which is set to requery once another account from the drop down box is selected. When I select the 1st account, the record shows. However, upon selecting the 2nd account, 3rd, etc, nothing shows. I can then re-select the 1st record & i see the account information - so i know it's not a problem with the form updating. 
The other strange thing is that upon selecting another account within the drop down box & then running the query from the query designer, the account information is retrieved for the 2nd / 3rd 4th record within the datasheet view. So, i know it isn't a problem with the query.

Any ideas on how to resolve? I've tried deleting the subform & re-inserting it (ensuring that the names match).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggeling with the same problem, I managed to resolve it: You need to delete any reference to the child / master fields within the subforms properties.